# Difference between /etc/init.d and /sbin/service

Tags: service, centos, init.d

What's the difference between starting daemons (tomcat for example) with /etc/init.d and /sbin/service? Is there a benefit to using one or the other?

Running CentOS release 5.8 (Final)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

/sbin/service simply runs the corresponding script in /etc/init.d  The advantage of running /sbin/service is that it sets up a "clean" environment first. From the service man page:

> service  runs  a  System V init script or upstart job in as
>   predictable an environment as possible, removing most environment
>   variables and with the current working directory set to /.